# How to use a function to calculate a complex problem using variables from user input and display the a result in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, math, button, user-input

I am trying to create code which users will use to calculate the amount of loan that they can get (loan amount) But it is Not working. The formula for calculating the loan amount is c = (a-1/3b-200)/e where a is the basic salary, b is the net pay, and e is the factor which depends on the number of years for the expected loan. My code is not displaying the result on clicking on the button.

I have tried assigning the variable c to the submit button for display. I have also tried using the custom calculate() function in vain. I am new to JavaScript programming your help will be appreciated greatly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
Enter the basic salary : <input id="first"><br>
Enter the net pay: <input id="second"><br>
Number of Years:
<select id="third">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select><br>
<script>

var a,b,c,d,e;
a=Number(document.getElementById("first").value);
b=Number(document.getElementById("second").value);
d=Number(document.getElementById("third").value);
if (d=1) {
e=0.034;
} else if (d=2) {
e=0.045;
} else if (d=3) {
e=0.055;
} else if (d=4) {
e=0.065;
}else {
e=0.080;
}
c= (a-1/3b-200)/e;
<script>
function calculate() {
  return (a-1/3b-200)/e;
} 
</script>
<button onclick="calculate()">Click me</button>


</body>
</html>
```

I would like to receive the loan amount on clicking the button. No error messages are displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues with the code you presented.

1:  Your calculation is invalid - There isn't(and can't be) a `3b` variable .
If you want to multiple the value from b by 3, then you need to say `(a-1/(3*b)-200)/e;`.

2: You have invalid html syntax - You've opened the script tag twice, but closed it once.
You can remove the tag before you create the calculate function.

3:  Your calculate function will only run calculations on the values available the first time the page loads.  Move the code that fetches the user's inputs into the calculate function.

4: Your `if` blocks when you assign `e` aren't checking for the value of `d`, it's assigning values using the single `=`.  If you want to see if `d` is equal to a value, you'd use `==`.

5: Finally, you haven't done anything with the calculated value, just returned it.   That doesn't make it visible to the user.  You can either alert it out instead of returning, or add an element to the page where you insert the results.

---

With those corrections, the result of the javascript looks like this.

```
function calculate() {
  var a,b,c,d,e;
  a=Number(document.getElementById("first").value);
  b=Number(document.getElementById("second").value);
  d=Number(document.getElementById("third").value);

  if (d==1) {
    e=0.034;
  } else if (d==2) {
    e=0.045;
  } else if (d==3) {
    e=0.055;
  } else if (d==4) {
    e=0.065;
  }else {
    e=0.080;
  }
  var result = (a-1/(3*b)-200)/e;
  alert(result);
  // OR, if you have an input for the results
  // document.getElementById('results').value=result
  //OR if you have a text element for the results
  // document.getElementById('results').innerText=result
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have saved me.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    Enter the basic salary : <input id="first" /><br />
    Enter the net pay: <input id="second" /><br />
    Number of Years:
    <select id="third">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option> </select
    ><br />
    <script>
      function calculate() {
        var a, b, c, d, e;
        a = Number(document.getElementById('first').value);
        b = Number(document.getElementById('second').value);
        d = Number(document.getElementById('third').value);
        if ((d = 1)) {
          e = 0.034;
        } else if ((d = 2)) {
          e = 0.045;
        } else if ((d = 3)) {
          e = 0.055;
        } else if ((d = 4)) {
          e = 0.065;
        } else {
          e = 0.08;
        }
        c = (a - (1 / 3) * b - 200) / e;
        alert(c);
      }
    </script>
    <button onclick="calculate()">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Some of the required changes in your code are:**

1. Move your logic into calculate() method
2. Remove the extra script tag from code
3. Use multiplication operator in formula

Comment: There are some very obvious errors remaining in that code so it won't work.

Comment: Answers should explain what they changed and why, not be games of spot-the-difference.

Comment: Ok , Adding explainations

Comment: You gave me some insights but the main error was using the assignment operator = instead of the equal to operand ==